# offscreen buffer blending from saveLayer( ) in skia

Tags: android, graphics, skia

having a doubt about saveLayer()
from the doc, saveLayer(nullptr, nullptr) would allocate an off-screen buffer and later it's composited back to original buffer when restore() is called.

How is that blended? is there a default blending mode for this case?

Comment: most likely its `SRC_OVER`

Comment: that's my guess too.  thanks!

Comment: sure, your welcome...